# Get closest larger number in an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, numbers

I have a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = {'CQI': np.linspace(1,15,15), 'Qm': [2,2,2,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8],
         'Rmax': np.array([78,193,449,378,490,616,466,567,666,772,873,711,797,885,948])/1024,
         'SNR_max': [-6.2369,-4.3591,-1.9319,0.1509,1.9976,4.7278,6.2231,8.0591,9.8585,11.8432,
                     13.4893,15.3598,17.4435,19.2155,np.inf]}     
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

and I want to find the closest value in 'SNR_max' column that is larger than a certain value. For example, for the value of 2.5, the closest larger value in 'SNR_max' is 4.7278. The return value would be the value of 'CQI'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
value = 2.5
idx_CQI = np.where(df['SNR_max']>value)[0][0]
>>> 5
CQI = df['SNR_max'][idx_CQI]
>>> 4.7278
```

First zero is for where the condtion `df['SNR_max']>value` is `True` in array `df['SNR_max']` which corresponds to idx `[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`, second zero is there to select the first element of it, *i.e.* `5`.

Hope this helps.